# if文を含むPythonの表記を1行にまとめたい

Tags: python

下記のようなPythonのコードがあります。
Pythonのポリシーに反するものだとは思いますが、他の言語からPythonを呼び出すにあたって、どうしても1行で全てを収めたいという場合があり、1行にまとめて実行したいと考えています。

```
testInt = 2
if testInt == 2:
    print("testInt is 2")
else:
    print("testInt is not 2")
print("finish!")
```

そこで、試しに以下のように書いてみたのですが、`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`となって実行できません。

```
testInt = 2;if testInt == 2:print("testInt is 2");else:print("testInt is not 2");print("finish!");
```

Pythonでは通常、`";"(セミコロン)`がなくても、改行扱いになりますが、セミコロンをつけることによっても改行扱いにできます。そのため、以下のように書いてもエラーにはなりません。

```
testInt = 2;print(testInt);
```

if文やfor文以外の文に関しては、セミコロンを使用するだけでうまく行くのですが、ifとforなどが入ってくると、1行にまとめられないため、何か良い方法があったら教えてください。

Comment: 参考までに、[6. Ternary Operators — Python Tips 0.1 documentation](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html#ternary-operators) には `(if_test_is_false, if_test_is_true)[test]` という形式も記載されています。`print(('testInt is not 2', 'testInt is 2')[testInt==2])`

Comment: これもとても使いやすいですね！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[三項演算子のように](https://note.nkmk.me/python-if-conditional-expressions/)記述することでワンライナーを実現できます。

```
testInt = 2; print("testInt is 2") if testInt == 2 else print("testInt is not 2"); print("finish!")
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Comment: print 関数の内部で条件式を使うこともできますよ。 `print('testInt is 2' if testInt == 2 else 'testInt is not 2')`